# Почему говорят "имя существительное" а не просто существительное?

Tags: морфология, значение-слов, недопустимая-метка

Собственно, разобраться в вопросе.

Comment: Подозреваю, калька с латинского "nomen substantivum".

Answer (score 3):

"Существительное" тоже говорят, но более точным название является "имя существительное". Если говорить об общей, "многоязычной" лингвистике, то в ней принято выделять **класс имен** (существительное, прилагательное, местоимение, как правило - числительное, иногда некоторые другие) и противопоставляемый ему **класс глаголов**. Остальные части речи являются либо комбинацией типов из этих двух классов, либо занимают обособленное, вспомогательное место. Поэтому использование слова "имя" в названии части речи вполне объяснимо, оно подчеркивает принадлежность к классу имен.

Answer (score 1):

У сущего или существующего, — всего «видимого и невидимого», должно быть и есть имя. Имя, принадлежащее существующему, — имя существительное, где *существительное* — определение, а *имя существительное* (полностью или только *существительное*) — часть речи; так говорят, определяя само слово *существительное* существительным.

Почему говорят *имя существительное* а не просто *существительное*? Потому, наверное, что есть контекст, подсказывающий как следует говорить.